# How to manipulate database info before displaying it in Django template?

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2, bbcode

So I've got a basic Django website setup that displays dynamic info from the database.

I would like to be able to manipulate the text coming out of the database so I can create BBCode parsers or whatever else I want. I'm pretty new to Django so I'm a little confused as to where this should be done.

These are my files so far...

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from forum.models import Post

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25], template_name="forum/forum.html")),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model = Post, template_name = 'forum/post.html')),
]
```

Forum.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <p>{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href="/forum/{{post.id}}"> {{ post.title }}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Functions.py

```
def bbcode(data):
    data2 = data + "some random text"

    return data2
```

All of those files are located inside of the "forum" directory located in the root project folder which is "coolsite".

So my understanding is that I need to import functions.py somewhere and use the bbcode() method to manipulate text being pulled from the database. That way it has been parsed once displayed on the "forum.html" template.

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I searched around and couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

How should I go about doing this exactly?

Comment: Kind of a broad question but it should be done in a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `ListView` methods. You will need to do some changes in your code:

- Set a custom view to your url config

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from forum.models import Post
from forum.views import PostList

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PostList.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model = Post, template_name = 'forum/post.html')),
]
```

- Create a custom view in your app (forum.views) based in a ListView

  ```
  # views.py

  from django.views.generic import ListView
  from forum.models import Post


  class PostList(ListView):

  model = Post
  template_name = "forum/forum.html"

  # here is where magic happens
  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
      context = super(PostList, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
      # context has the same context that you get in your template before
      # so you can take data and work with it before return it to template
      return context
  ```

You can found docs for [Class-Based Views here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/class-based-views/#class-based-views)